# Saving Data in HTML format

Tags: asp.net

In management section of a web site,i saw a MS-Word like control that user writes text with word effects and then she saves that text on a database and then this data displayed formatted in another part of database.
i guess this control saves formatted text in html format and then uses a literal control for displaying this data.
my question is wich control can do this and how do i use this control?
I'm using ASP.Net 4.0 and C# for programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Microsoft does not have a rich text box available in standard .NET.  Check out [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor.NET_released).

Comment: this is exactly the control i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure, that this is what you are searching for -> 
http://freetextbox.com/

[image]
<sub>(source: [freetextbox.com](http://freetextbox.com/images/example1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I didn't see control, which looks like word 2007. I worked only with freetexteditor.